# How to use Zip<TFirst,TSecond>(IEnumerable<TFirst>, IEnumerable<TSecond>)?

Tags: c#, .net, list, lambda, tuples

Instead of having an index inside a for loop, I would like to traverse 2 lists of the same length and have a respective variable assigned to each member of those lists.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0

In this documentation by Microsoft, the first application had an example, and I understood how to use it, however, I can't seem to make the second one work, and it's what I need for a problem I'm working on.

Here's a sample code to illustrate:

```
var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var words = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
foreach (var (number, word) in Zip(numbers,words))   //this doesn't work
{
    //do something
}
```

However, the code above throws multiple errors. I tried to manipulate it into looking like the example in microsoft's documention and I got it working. However, it looks too redundant as you can see in the sample code below:

```
var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var words = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
foreach (var (number, word) in numbers.Zip(words, (number,word) => (number,word))) //this lambda expression looks too repetitive
{
    //do something
}
```

Can anyone help me clean it up?

Comment: It isn't redundant, it is _flexible_. You could also have `(n,w) => (n,w)` or `(n,w) => new { number = n, word = w }` or `(n,w) => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(n,w)`. You can't expect the method to know which you want. Having said that, you could also create your own `Zip` extension method that returns a `ValueTuple`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enumerable.Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0#definition)

> Produces a sequence of tuples with elements from the two specified
> sequences.

You will need to use either

```
Enumerable.Zip(numbers,words)
```

or the extension method

```
numbers.Zip(words)
```

Also the deconstructed tuple `var (first, second)` is *C# 7.0* or later

**Example**

```
var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var words = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
foreach (var (first, second) in numbers.Zip(words)) 
   Console.WriteLine($"{first},{second}");
```

**Output**

```
1,one
2,two
3,three
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zqOp9X)

---

If you are using the *old and busted* *.Net Framework* or pre *.net core 3*, then you don't have much of an option other than use the `Func` parameter. However, you could use a sneakily selector method, delegate, local method, etc

**Given**

```
private static (T1, T2) Selector<T1,T2>(T1 t1, T2 t2) => (t1, t2);
```

**Usage**

```
foreach (var (i, s) in numbers.Zip(words,Selector))
```

Or just write your own extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<(TFirst,TSecond)> Zip<TFirst, TSecond>(
   this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
   IEnumerable<TSecond> second)
   => first.Zip(second, (first1, second1) => (first1, second1));
```

Comment: I have already tried this approach but there's an error saying, "Method 'Zip' has two parameter(s) but is invoked with 1 argument(s)"

Comment: @MKSpan I guess you are using the old and busted .net framework?

Comment: @TheGeneral I don't think it's fair to call .NET Framework "busted" -- it's still very much in support. Earlier versions of .NET Core don't have that overload, either

Comment: @canton7 earlier versions of .net core are busted too :)

Comment: @TheGeneral I write in .NET Framework every day and it's perfectly fine. Core is certainly better, but not to the point that 4.x is broken.

Comment: @DavidG I would have to agree with that.

Comment: The new simplified Zip method is only available in .NET 6. Before this you will have to use the one that has the delegate.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It's available in .NET Core 3.0+, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__)

Comment: Ah, so it is. Never mind my comment then.

Comment: I think I would name `Selector` `AsValueTuple` or `AsTuple` and possibly have 7 versions of it...

Comment: @NetMage you are likely right there, or just upgrade :)

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to use it as a method not a extension method first of all you need to use three parameters:

```
Zip<TFirst,TSecond,TResult>(IEnumerable<TFirst>, IEnumerable<TSecond>, Func<TFirst,TSecond,TResult>)
```

Thrid one is Func. So basically what you are achieving by second piece of code is:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };    
Func<int, string, (int, string)> func = (integer, str) => (integer, str);
var numbersAndWords = Enumerable.Zip(numbers, words, func);

foreach (var item in numbersAndWords)
{
    //do smth
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

.NET core accepts two parameters as you want:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };
var numbersAndWords = Enumerable.Zip(numbers, words);

foreach (var item in numbersAndWords)
{
    //do smth
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```